# Changed mind after creating gitignore and the first few commits

Tags: git

How do I get the files added to the next commit so the master branch gets updated with the file(s) that are no longer marked to be ignored.

For example, say I had in gitignore .htaccess but now I remove it... how can I get the repository updated with the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

If those files are no longer selected by `.gitignore` rule, they should be listed immediately in a `git status`.

A simple `git add .htaccess` would be enough.
(Don't forget to add and commit the `.gitingore` as well, in order to record the change of ignore selection rules)

Comment: I'm sorry, please bear with my ignorance... but if I add '.gitignore' doesn't that mean it will then be included and added to the repository? I had  '.gitignore' as the first line entry in the file.

Comment: @BillieM `.gitignore` is supposed to be part of the repo. And a `.gitignore` file would generally not include `.gitignore`.

Comment: `.gitignore` is usually part of the repo. Check out [gitignore(5)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) for alternatives that don't have to be published.